Managing Email Consent in SFMC Journey
In my SFMC setup, I handle email consent as follows:

I have an automation that runs hourly to update the All Subscribers
status based on opt-in/opt-out information from the Subscription
Center.
When a user opts out via the Subscription Center, their status is immediately updated to Inactive in All Subscribers, ensuring they do not receive any further emails.

Currently, my journeys allow all contacts to enter, regardless of their email consent status. I rely on SFMC's built-in mechanism, which ensures that only contacts with an Active status in All Subscribers receive emails. I do not explicitly check for email consent (e.g., in a Decision Split) before each email activity in the journey.
This approach simplifies my journeys, as SFMC excludes unsubscribed or held contacts automatically. However, I’m wondering:

Is this approach considered best practice?
Should I add explicit consent checks (e.g., via Contact Data or Attribute Groups) before sending emails in journeys?


As long as the subscriber's status (opt-in/opt-out) is updated in the All Subscribers List, there is no need for additional steps to validate it. The system is designed to handle this automatically.
However, it's worth to be aware of is the send classification defined for each email send activity within the journey:

Commercial Send: this checks the subscriber's status and only sends emails if the status is active.
Transactional Send: this does not check the subscriber's status. Emails will be sent even if the recipient has unsubscribed.


I would say this isn't best practice - for multiple reasons.

Relying on All Subscribers will only prevent you from sending emails. You might not support additional channels today, but adopting a multichannel to consent management already today will give you a more solid foundation for the future.
You will have inaccurate audience sizes. Imagine a sendable data extension, used e.g. for a journey entry event. If this is built based on consent status of your contacts, it will always show a higher count than the actual sent emails. You will have more reliable volume expectation when working with a master data extension based on consent data.
Using Exit Criteria to look at the consent status of your contacts currently in the journey will ensure they will be remove once progressing from a wait step and into a subsequent activity in the journey canvas.

Also do observe same considerations about the transactional vs commercial send classifications as provided by Duc Le.
